# Receiving multiple lines turn by turn over a socket at client side

Tags: java, file, sockets

I am sending a file line by line over socket using while loop. What should be coded on the client side that on each iteration at server side when a string is sent, it is also received on each iteration of while loop on client side?

My Server side code:

```
File file = new File("Text.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
String str = scan.nextLine();
pw.println(str);
}
```

Using PrintWriter's object pw, I am sending data over socket. Please mention approach for receiving side.

Here is the client side:

```
String str = br.readLine(); 
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: If only there were a method to `read` a `Line`...

Comment: @Kayaman Already using br.readLine() function but couldn't figure out how to apply loop on this statement so that it is executed and receive lines again and again

Comment: What's the code in the question, and how is it relevant to sockets? Is that the client side code? If so, show the server side code too.

Comment: @Kayaman, No, its serverside code. pw.println(str) is used here for sending string over socket. I have shown only the code which reads lines from file and send it to the client

Comment: Then show the client side code. Remember, `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` when the stream is finished.

Comment: @Kayaman 
String str = br.readLine();
System.out.println(str);
I want to loop through this

Comment: Edit your question to include the code. Do not put the code in the comments. I don't read unformatted code in comments.

Comment: @Kayaman , edited question!!!

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` at end-of-stream, so the common idiom is to perform read inside the condition part.

```
String str = null;
while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with str
}
```